# Code to turn blackberry off

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde, jde

Is there a command or piece of code that I can use to **switch the blackberry off from within my app**? I have created a simple app that consists of a button, now what I want is for the device to shut down whenever the button is clicked. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes [Device.requestPowerOff(boolean allowAutoStart)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Device.html#requestPowerOff%28boolean%29)